# Ntpdate is not running on my machine

Tags: ntp, ntpdate

I am trying to give IPv6 support for NTP server in my ntp scripts.

Yet i have set the IPv6 NTP server directly by giving its IP in ntp.conf and restart the ntpd .

Now in the logs of ntpq flash value become 1600 and stratum is set to 16 but the original stratum of this server is 4.

Then i tried whether ntpdate is running or not....and found that the ntpdate is not running.

Now how i can run ntpdate command or how i can correct the flash value..

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ntpdate` is not a daemon that runs all the time, it's intended for interactive use or in scripts to poll an NTP server once. `ntpd` is the daemon process you need to look for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i know ntpdate is not a deamon its a command to quickly sync with ntp server..... Now back to the question,stratum of ntp server is 16 which might be due to flash=1600 in ntpq logs....now what can i do to be in sync with that NTP server

Comment: You cannot sync to a server at stratum 16, as it is itself not synced.

Comment: Thanks MadHatter sir for your response... The actual stratum of that server is 4....i confirmed it when i set that server by using its IPv4 address and when i am trying to set the same server using IPv6 then it is giving stratum = 16 which might be due to flash =1600

Comment: So it's your client that's at stratum 16, when (and only when) you try to bind over ipv6?   If so, are you sure you've got end-to-end v6 connectivity?  There's no firewall on the server blocking v6 connections?

Comment: Client machine showing the stratum of server is 16.... Yes i checked the end to end connectivity by Ping6 command,,both server and client are pinging each other...yes there is no firewall

Comment: What does `ntptrace ip:v6:of:server` give on the client?